# Modulus operation to find unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving, natural-numbers

If the $5$ digit number $538xy$ is divisible by $3,7$ and $11,$ find $x$ and $y$ .

How to solve this problem with the help of modulus operator ?

---

I was checking the divisibility for 11, 3:

$5-3+8-x+y = a ⋅ 11$ and $5+3+8+x+y = b⋅3$ and I am getting more unknowns ..

Comment: What do you mean by modulus operator?

Comment: Sorry , what I mean is that "23 = 3 mod 5 " this mod ...

Comment: Well, I know how to do it without mod

Comment: may I know the answer.

Comment: Hint: $538xy = 53800 + 10x + y$

Comment: yeah like that I did , checking the divisibility for 11, 3

Comment: 5-3+8-x+y = a $\cdot$ 11

Comment: 5+3+8+x+y = b$\cdot$3

Comment: and I am getting more unknowns ..

Comment: I am sorry what is OP. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From modulus 11,

$$
53800 + 10x + y \equiv 5 - 3 + 8 - x + y \equiv -1-x+y \equiv 0 \pmod {11}\\
\implies y\equiv 1+x \pmod {11}
$$
but $y$ and $x$ are digits, so $0\le y\le 9$ and $1\le 1+x \le 10$, so it must hold that $y=1+x$.

From modulus 3,
$$
53800 + 10x + y \equiv 5 + 3 + 8 + x + (x+1) \equiv 2+2x \equiv 0 \pmod {3}\\
\implies x\equiv -1 \pmod {3}
$$
so $x=2,5,8$.

Eventually, from modulus 7,
$$
53800 + 10x + y \equiv 5 + 3x + (x+1) = 6+4x \equiv 0 \pmod {7}\\
\implies x\equiv 2 \pmod {7}
$$
so $x=2,9$.

The only choice is thus $x=2$, $y=3$.

Comment: Here in  $5 + 3 + 8 + x + x + 1 = 17 + 2x  $, $17 = 2 ( mod 3) $, $2x = 0~ (mod~ 3)$, is what became $2 + 2x$ , is my under standing correct.?

Comment: I don't get the $2x=0 \pmod 3$ part

Comment: sorry then, can you just tell me how you converted $17 + 2x $ congruent to $2 + 2x$

Comment: $17\equiv 2\pmod 3$, $2x = 2x \pmod 3$

Comment: Thanks that is , $2x = 0 \times 3 + 2x$

Comment: yes, that is it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109311/discussion-between-ajit-joseph-and-exodd).

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution with divisibility properties only:

$$11\mid 538xy \implies 11\mid y-x+8-3+5 = y-x+10$$

so $$11\mid y-x-1\implies y-x-1=0$$

Also $$3\mid 538xy \implies 3\mid y+x+8+3+5 = y+x+16$$ so $$3\mid  y+x+1 = 2(x+1)\implies x\in\{2,5,8\}$$

Now try for each pair $(x,y)\in \{(2,3),(5,6),(8,9)\}$ if $7\mid 538xy$...

Comment: how did you convert $y-x+10$ to $y-x-1$

Comment: Substract 11....

Answer (score 1):

As $53800\equiv208\pmod{231},$

$$10x+y=231z-208$$

Now $99\ge10x+y\ge0$

$$99\ge231z-208\ge0$$

$$\implies 2>307/231\ge z\ge208/231>0$$

$$\implies z=1$$

Consequently $$10x+y=23\iff y=23-10x$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: why you choose 231.? why not any other number .?

Comment: @Ajit,$$3\cdot7\cdot11=?$$

Comment: So after reaching $y = 23-10x$, use trial and error .??

Comment: @Ajit, $$9\ge23-10x\ge0\iff-9+23\le10x\le23$$ right?

Comment: Understood and thanks.